# Will one query run faster than multiple queries, if they are deleting the same amount of records

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
Table company
companyid | companyname | owner |
5         |coffecompany |Mike   |
6         |juicecompany |Mike   |
```

For some reason, I need to use this:

```
DELETE FROM company WHERE companyid='5';
DELETE FROM company WHERE companyid='6';
```

instead of

```
DELETE FROM company WHERE owner='Mike';
```

But I wonder if the second choice run faster, if it does, will it run much faster? In the future, I may have to use it to delete a large amount of records, so I really need to know.

Comment: SQL Server, or SQL in general?

Comment: Since it's a benchmarking question, it should be specific to an RDBMS. so which one is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delete from company where companyId in (5, 6);` should always be faster, even though the difference might be negligible if eg. you've got proper indexes, no concurrent queries, no issues with locking etc.

Note that my query is for MS SQL, if your database server allows using the same construct (ie. specifying all the values in such concise way), you should probably use it, if not, go with something like `delete from company where companyId = 5 or companyId = 6;` Also, don't use string literals if `companyid` is a number (is the table column actually a number, or a text?).

In any case, it gives the server more lee-way in implementing the actual operation, and DB servers tend to be very good at query optimization.

One possible bottle-neck for deletion could be in the transaction logs, however. It might very well be that if you're deleting a huge amount of rows at once, it would be better to do a few separate deletes in separate transactions to fit within transaction size limits.

Comment: you should make more clear that your query is a third variant
wich is faster than both in the question, as it avoids the string compares and is 1 query

Answer (score 1):

Generally, SQL is language operating on sets of data so second query will be much faster for huge amount of rows.

First choice might be slower as you'll have to send query text as many times as you have rows to delete. Imagine network traffic if you want to delete 1 000 000 rows.

On small amounts of rows probably you won't be able to see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle, think of using bind variable :

execute immediate 'DELETE FROM company WHERE companyid=:ID' USING 6;

But other than that, there is no specific answer to your question, you need to benchmark yourself, it depends on the amount of data, your indexes etc...

Answer (score 0):

When using `Where` clause in a query, RDBMS will go to find the result set applying the condition.
Normally RDBMS will do a full-table-scan to find the result set, it means that any records will be investigated to see if the condition is matched. 
Based on the table size that will be time consuming.
Above approach will differed when when the column(s) listed in the where condition are indexed.
Indexing is a way of sorting a number of records on multiple fields. Creating an index on a field in a table creates another data structure which holds the field value, and pointer to the record it relates to. This index structure is then sorted, allowing Binary Searches to be performed on it. 
**As a simplified sample:** 
A linear search (full-table-scan) on the field `A` of table `T` containing N records would require an average of N/2 accesses to find a value.
If 'A' field is indexed then a sorted binary search will requiring an average of log2 N block accesses.
 Asuming that `N=1,000,000`  then we will have

```
N/2 = 500,000 
log2 1000000 = 19.93 = 20
```

Instantly we can see this is a drastic improvement.
It looks like the companyid is the primary key of company table, if so any primary key column will be indexed automatically by RDMS and the search will be more effective than searching by `owner`.